# Getting "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error on running .c function in objective-c .m class, work fine on simulator but not on device

Tags: iphone, c

First off my code was working fine on simulator but it does not work on device.
I have client.h and client.c file in which I have declared a method

`extern int getConfigeFile(char *pFileName, char *pFilePath);`

in client.h and implement this on client.c

Now i am calling this method from my Appdelegate and i also included header file of client.h

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
      int status = getConfigeFile("FileName" , "Document Directory path here"); <-- Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on this line

...
```

Comment: Those `char*`s should probably be `NSString*`s

Comment: are you able to step in to the function or does it simply throw a bad access when trying to call it

Comment: not able to step into function

Comment: BAD access at function call and arguments are same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .c file check if there is any macro defined like

```
#defined DATALENGTH 256
```

which is used in function for constant value , which should be less than 128 or 64 in your case i.e

```
#defined DATALENGTH 64
```